# What is the equivalent of Android TextView in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, textview

When I searched for "Android TextView equivalent in iOS" in Google and StackOverflow I expected to find a quick answer but it took a little searching and switching up of keywords. I am posting this Q&A pair so that other people can have the quick answer for these keywords.

I've been doing Android programming for about a year and now I am starting on iOS. All of the tutorials I've been doing use `UILabel` to display text but I want multiline text that could be paragraphs long and UILabel doesn't seem suited to that.

This one came up, but that was the wrong direction (iOS to Android):

[iOS to Android: How to display a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043373/ios-to-android-how-to-display-a-textview)

And here are some other "equivalent" questions but not the one I wanted:

- [What is the equivalent of Android's "Spannable" in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044180/what-is-the-equivalent-of-androids-spannable-in-objective-c)
- [What is the equivalent of Android content provider in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371736/what-is-the-equivalent-of-android-content-provider-in-ios)
- [What is the equivalent of Android permissions in iOS development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482385/what-is-the-equivalent-of-android-permissions-in-ios-development)
- [What is the equivalent of Android's Html.fromHtml() in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289542/what-is-the-equivalent-of-androids-html-fromhtml-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of an Android `TextView` in iOS is `UILabel` and `UITextView`. The one you want for large amounts of text is `UITextView`. Below are descriptions taken from the documentation:

[UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html)

> The UITextView class implements the behavior for a scrollable,
>   multiline text region. The class supports the display of text using
>   custom style information and also supports text editing. You typically
>   use a text view to display multiple lines of text, such as when
>   displaying the body of a large text document.

[UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html)

> The UILabel class implements a read-only text view. You can use this
>   class to draw one or multiple lines of static text, such as those you
>   might use to identify other parts of your user interface.

[UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html)

> A UITextField object is a control that displays editable text and
>   sends an action message to a target object when the user presses the
>   return button. You typically use this class to gather small amounts of
>   text from the user and perform some immediate action, such as a search
>   operation, based on that text.

Here are some links for further research:

- [Using Text Kit to Draw and Manage Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html) (documentation)
- [Text Kit Tutorial in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift)
- [Using Text Kit to Manage Text in Your iOS Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-text-kit-ios-programming-guide/)
- [ios: best way to display variable-length, multi-line text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747602/ios-best-way-to-display-variable-length-multi-line-text)