# Convert Android Font equivalent in iOS

Tags: android, ios, fonts

I have checked almost everywhere but did not find a proper answer for this.
How the Android text size which is in SP will be use in iOS.
Example:

```
<TextView
                        android:text="My Text"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

What will be the equivalent in iOS.
If I give font size 18 which looks small in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: This may help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516948/what-is-the-equivalent-of-android-textview-in-ios

Comment: @Ishtiyak that doesn't answer what OP is asking, OP is asking about font sizes, the link you've provded doesn't talk about that at all ?